# Jump is not moving the character on Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The debug log for the jump function shows up in the console correctly, but I can't find any way to write the code that actually makes the character move up on the Y axis when I press the button.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KittenController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
    Animator animator;

    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;

    private float idleTimer;

    float horizontal;
    float vertical;
    //int direction;

    Vector2 lookDirection = new Vector2(1, 0);
    Vector2 jumping = new Vector2(0, 100);

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        idleTimer = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 move = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

        // Jump Movement
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Jump();
            Debug.Log("Space Pressed");
            // animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

        if (move.magnitude == 0)
        {
            idleTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            //Debug.Log("Idle Time is : " + idleTimer);
        }
        else
        {
            idleTimer = 0;
        }

        if (!Mathf.Approximately(move.x, 0.0f) || !Mathf.Approximately(move.y, 0.0f))
        {
            lookDirection.Set(move.x, move.y);
            lookDirection.Normalize();
            //Debug.Log("X is: " + lookDirection);
        }

        //animator.SetFloat("Look X", lookDirection.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Move X", lookDirection.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", move.magnitude);

    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;

        position.x = position.x + speed * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
        position.y = position.y + speed * vertical * Time.deltaTime;

        rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
    }

    void Jump()
    {
        //rigidbody2d.AddForce(jumping, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        //rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2d.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        rigidbody2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;

        Debug.Log("Jumping");
    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:unity2d] is a synonym for [tag:unity3d]

Comment: Use a debugger. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the Jump() method and step through your code. Inspect all properties that are relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe jumping, but rightafter, almost at the same time you are setting the y position with the `rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);` in the `FixedUpdate()`

First dont use the fixed update if there is specific need of a constant delta time (physics or a maybe a replay system). You should use the `Update()` instead.

Second, usually handling movement setting the transform with code **and** also with physics (setting a velocity to the rigidbody) is not a good idea. You need to choose wether your object moves with physics or to set the `transform.position` in the code (maybe applying physics also, but coded by yourself).
Take into account that if you set a `transform.position` directly in the code, very probably won't make sense with the physics calculations if the object is moving with physics, so unexpected results will take place.

I would remove all the code in the `FixedUpadte()` and most of the code, and try just to work out that the jump works, with `rigidbody2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;` or with `rigidbody2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, 1.0f),  ForceMode2D.Impulse)`.
The I would try to work out the movement separatedly, maybe with `rigidbody2d.AddForce(new Vector2(1.0f, 0f),  ForceMode2D.Force)`. Then maybe try to work them out together for the respective inputs.

I you want to handle the position setting the `transform.position` directly instead of using physics, I would also split the problem into smaller ones, first achieve movement maybe with

```
position.x = position.x + speed * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
```

And then the jump. For the `position.y` you may to apply uniformly accelerated motion physics and apply that logic to your vertical position when you jump, or maybe figure a type of jump of your own with a movement you define.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to make it work but the character will just go up infinitely.

I tried "rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce * Time.deltaTime" which worked but it seems to produce a different jump height every time. Is there a way to control that better?

Comment: Thanks again. I figured out the movement! Just gotta figure out the animations and stuff now :)

Comment: you're welcome. good luck :)